# Remove any url parameters on 404 redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, parameters, http-status-code-404

My company recently changed it's website, to a brand new one, but in the Google search results, there are specific links, that aren't exist.

I have redirected the 404 error to the index.php, but the url parameters remain there.
I don't want any complicated error handling, just redirect the 404 to index.php and remove ANY url parameters.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting 404 error with .htaccess via 301 for SEO etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363520/redirecting-404-error-with-htaccess-via-301-for-seo-etc)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are redirecting using .htaccess.

Make 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not redirect 404 erros wildly! They have a purpose and that is to tell, that this link is not existing. Redirect only *old* links which do not exists anymore via 301.

In the .htaccess file add something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/oldsite1.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/oldsite2.html$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=old$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R=301,L]
```

For the syntax of RewriteCondition check the manual.