# Redirecting 404 using 301 redirect is redirecting existing pages to Home page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've just re-developed one of my websites. The structure has changed therefore I need to globally redirect the **old non existent** pages that are still currently ranked on Google (50 or so pages) to redirect to my new website's **HOME PAGE**.

The structure has basically changed from pages - example:

`www.website.com/page1.php`
`www.website.com/page2.htm`
`www.website.com/page3.php`
... and so forth

to

`www.website.com/page1/`
`www.website.com/page2/`
`www.website.com/page3/`
... and so forth

After a bit of Googling, I came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108864/3364730) on SO

When I add:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

to my `.htaccess` file, the redirect (to the home page) for non-existing pages works - Great!

**BUT now every link in my navigation / side panel on my new website (that exists) is also being redirected to the home page. So I cannot navigate through my website!**

**So for example when I click the about us link `www.website.com/about-us/` or any other of my other 50 pages (regardless what they're named), the 301 redirect solution above keeps re-directing me to home page (as is if those pages didn't exist).**

I want to globally redirect the **old non existent** pages that are still currently ranked on Google (50 or so pages) to redirect to my new website's **HOME PAGE** ... NOT my website's existing links.

Why is this? I thought the 404 redirect using 301 method would only target pages that DON'T exist.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: write a  404 page and using .htacess  set your custom 404 page and on that page set redirect to whatever page you like

Comment: What is `about-us`? Is it a directory or a file, or is it rather `about-us.php`?

Comment: @OlafDietsche ... a directory file `www.website.com/about-us/` with index.php being the default page in the `/about-us/` directory

Answer (score 2):

To redirect **/page.php** to **/page** , you can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [L,R,NE]
```

You can change R to R=301 to make the redirect permanent.

Comment: I am trying to find out why my NEW websites links in the navigation are resolving / redirecting to the HOME page with `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]`

Comment: That's because of your rule as it rewrites everything but existing files to / .

Comment: I am also talking about globally redirecting *any* non existent page (that's still ranked on Google) to my home page ... not 1 specific page. My real problem is that my existing website links aren't working (they are being treated like they don't exist - please see my post)

Comment: "it rewrites everything but existing files to /" ... but my problem is that it is rewriting existing file too

Answer (score 0):

The rule is applied as follows

1. Check if `about-us` matches the pattern `.`, yes it does.
2. Check if the conditions match, `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. It is a directory, so yes it is not a file.
3. Everything matches -> apply the rule.

---

If you don't want a directory to match, you may say so by

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

So the complete rewrite rule would be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L,R]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301` ([permanent redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)). *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).